# Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String

Tags: android

This is my model class Users.java

```
public class Users {

    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String password;


    public Users(){ }
    public Users(String name, String phone, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

This is the output:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.fworld.chochoandnuts, PID: 29372
>       com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertString(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:425)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:216)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:178)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:47)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:592)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:562)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:432)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:231)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:79)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:203)
>           at com.fworld.chochoandnuts.LoginActivity$4.onDataChange(LoginActivity.java:127)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:179)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29372 SIG: 9 Process 29372 terminated.

[image: screeshot]

Answer (score 0):

In getReference("user") ;. Try that. Or whatever value you have in Firebase